# Sending Access reports by email as HTML

Tags: html, vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access report that contains records of clients from one table (including the email address) and linked grouped records from other tables fetched by a Query.

I want to send the content of the report to each client separately in the body of the email (not as an attachment), I am able to get the text put in the body of the email but without the formatting and without the picture in the header.

I used the following code which runs behind a click of a button. I would appreciate if anyone can help with the formatting issue AND if there is a way I can automate sending the emails for my 200+ clients without clicking the button each time (like a loop or something):

```vb
Private Sub Command70_Click()
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
    Dim appOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim MailOutlook As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim RTFBody
    Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set MailOutlook = appOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "report1", acFormatHTML, "Report.htm", , , , acExportQualityScreen
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.OpenTextFile("Report.htm", ForReading, False, TristateTrue)
    RTFBody = f.ReadAll
    f.Close
    With MailOutlook
        .To = Me.Email.Value
        .CC = "anwarmirza.ridha@gmail.com"
        .Subject = Me.CR_Number & " " & Me.English_Name & " Weekly Report"
        .HTMLBody = "Dear Supplier" & Chr$(13) & Chr$(13) & _
                     RTFBody
                     
        .Send
        
    End With
    
    Set MailOutlook = Nothing
    Set appOutlook = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MS Access reports are specialized rich text formats, conversion to HTML is not easily available. You would need to rebuild your report with HTML markup. However, there is another approach.

Consider creating an [Outlook email template](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-email-message-template-43ec7142-4dd0-4351-8727-bd0977b6b2d1) (.oft) with all needed images, colors, fonts, and other formatting with placeholders such as `%...%` markers:

> Dear %ClientName%:
>
> Thank you for purchase of %product% for %totalsales% on %salesdate%. We appreciate your business of %years% years.
>
> %salestable%
>
> Best wishes,
> MyCompany Management

Then, have MS Access loop through a recordset of email details and text for message body to fill in placeholders. Handle any date/current/percent formatting in SQL or VBA. Because you need a group level multi-record summary, run two loops at 1) client level and 2) sales level.

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT ClientID, ClientName, ...email details... FROM myClientsTable"
Set clientRST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

Do While Not clientRST.EOF
    Set MailOutlook = appOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Path\To\ClientEmail.oft")

    strSQL = "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 ...sales details..." _
              & " FROM mySalesTable" _
              & " WHERE ClientID = " & clientRST!ClientID
    Set salesRST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordSet(strSQL)

    ' TABLE COLUMNS
    strTable = "<table><th>"
    For i = 1 to salesRST.Fields.Count
        strTable = strTable & "<td>" & salesRST.Fields(i-0).Name & "</td>"
    Next i
    strTable = strTable & "</th>"

    ' TABLE ROWS
    salesRST.MoveFirst
    While Not salesRst.EOF 
        strTable = strTable & "<tr>"
        For i = 1 to salesRST.Fields.Count
            strTable = strTable & "<td>" & salesRST.Fields(i-0).Value & "</td>"
        Next i
        strTable = strTable & "</tr>"
        salesRST.MoveNext
    Wend
    strTable = strTable & "</table>"
    salesRST.Close

    With MailOutlook
        ' DYNAMIC RECIPEINT
        .To = clientRST!Email
        .CC = "anwarmirza.ridha@gmail.com"

        ' DYNAMIC SUBJECT
        .Subject = clientRST!CR_Number & " " & clientRST!English_Name & " Weekly Report"

        ' REPLACE PLACEHOLDERS
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "%ClientName%", clientRST!ClientName)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "%product%", clientRST!product)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "%totalsales%", clientRST!totalsales)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "%salesdate%", clientRST!salesdate)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "%years%", clientRST!client_years)

        ' ADD SALES TABLE
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "%salestable%", strTable)

        .Send 
    End With

    Set MailOutlook = Nothing
    clientRST.MoveNext
Loop

clientRST.Close
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but not sure of the Outloo template will sove my issue. My reports are linked to queries pulling data from differenet tables, the result can be one record to few tens of records. Hence placeholders mightnot work in my case, Any sugestion plz? Also I wounder if I can list the records in a table within the body of the teh email.

Comment: But a single query can join many tables, varying in number of records that we loop here. Do you have sub reports? You can add an HTML table after the email message.

Comment: No subreports, just a single report that will pull weekly sales records for clients, The report is grouped to show the sales records of each client seperatly in a tabular format. This is basically wat I need to send in the body of the email. Thank you.

Comment: You can ouput a report to a HTML file - but they suck, and look really bad. Access has internal PDF abilites (even without any PDF drivers installed). When you send a report to PDF, then  you get 100% correct rendering. You can now launch a report, and try the export as HTML - but they don't look very good at all. I suggest PDF files.

Comment: @AnwarMirza, still use template for any image design and build sales table dynamically with HTML `<table>`. See edit with two level loop through clients query and sales query. Code needs adjustments and testing. Add [html markup](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style.asp) for further styling.

Comment: Thanks a lot Parfait for your help. I think this should be the solution, I will try it.

Comment: Thank you Ablbert, unfortunaltey attachments will not be a good solution for majority of my lazy clients!! Thanks for the kind help dear.

Comment: Parfait, you made my day, thanks a million. Your idea worked perfectly, I am doig some cosmetic teething now. SUPER.

Comment: @Parfait, new requirement just popped, few clients asked to filter their data using specific keywords (as they are not intretsed to see long list of sales records each week). I am storing these keywords in a seperate table tblKeywords which contains ClientID and Keyword, now how can I apply the selection based on this extract criteria plz? Appreciate your kind help with any suggestion.

Comment: Forgot to mention that keywords are related to the "Product" field, they basically want to filter by specific brands or models, say "Kenwood, Samsung, iPhone12, HP...etc"

Comment: You will need to ask a new question but research Access SQL joins for keyword search. One way is a cross join of current query to keyword table with `WHERE` condition using `LIKE`.